# Does ancestry matter when merging to/from a release branch?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

We're in the process of creating a Subversion repository to house a codebase that is not currently under version control. In our current model, each release has a mainline "bucket" (call it 5.6) and multiple bugfix only "buckets" (5.6.1, 5.6.2, etc). This maps pretty well to the SVN model of having a trunk with multiple release branches, although our layout would be flattened out a bit like so:

- 5.6

  - trunk, etc
- 5.6.x

  - trunk, etc

The expectation will be that changes will be cherrypicked back and forth between 5.6/trunk and 5.6.x/trunk as needed. The release branches will never be reintegrated.

In this situation, does it matter whether 5.6.x/trunk is *actually* an `svn copy` of 5.6/trunk? Is there potential to run into merge conflicts if they're just two independent folders with no shared ancestry (as far as SVN is aware)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your branches are svn copies of your trunk you want to merge back, everything is fine. In the other way you need to use **--ignore-ancestry**

Note: if you merge files with same name, but different ancestries, files will be **replaced**, not merged. Usually this is very bad, difficult to detect and will cause all sort of strange problems (build problems, newly introduced bugs..etc..).  A Tree-Conflict arises only if you changed the merge destination in same time. You can avoid this by using **--ignore-ancestry**